# Rendering multiple modals programmatically in same component- vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

In my component, there are three pop up modal with different content. By clicking particular button, i have to open that pop up modal.

Here i am doing kind of this
**for button 1 -**

```
<s-button type="button" class="bl_btn" @click="onClickProdOpen">
      Product Details
  </s-button>
```

**For this modal 1 will be**

```
<s-modal v-model="isShowPopup1" :title="$t('LBL_PROD_CONT')"
    <my-component-one 
         :pageId ="this.$options.name"
         :popupDefaultTab="popupOpenDefaultTab"
         :onClickClose="onClickclose" 
    />
```

**Here is button click method for one button. Like this mutiple on click event for different modal.**

```
methods: {
  onClickProdOpen() {
   this.isShowPopup1 = true;
   this.popupOpenDefaultTab = 0;
}
}
```

<s-modal is custom modal part and content will be different. So, i am repeating this modal code just changing the content means passing different child components (MyComponentOne, MyComponentTwo....).

So, How to make it switch case statement to not to repeat the modal code mutiple times just changing the inside content component only?  Any suggestion will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

One option could be to put the state of each modal in an object. That way you don't need to have a data attribute for each modal.

If the content inside the modal is similar enough, you could use a v-for, using the index as the key in the same way.

```
    <b-modal v-model="modal_states[1]">Modal 1</b-modal>
    <b-button @click="openModal(1)">Open 1</b-button>
    
    <b-modal v-model="modal_states[2]">Modal 2</b-modal>
    <b-button @click="openModal(2)">Open 2</b-button>
    
    <b-modal v-model="modal_states[3]">Modal 3</b-modal>
    <b-button @click="openModal(3)">Open 3</b-button>
```

```
  data: {
    modal_states: {},
  },
  methods: {
    openModal(index){
      this.modal_states = {[index.toString()]:true}
    }
  },
```

https://codepen.io/timfranklin/pen/abWEwLy?editors=1111